# How do we make PDFs reflowable?

Tags: pdf, conversion, pdf-reader, epub, pdfcreator

I read news that Adoble released some Mobile SDK that would make PDFs reflowable. Is such technology out yet? Does involve converting a standard PDF to a reflowable? If so, how do we do it? Or is it based on a software that dynamically reflows content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflow the contents of Adobe PDF documents](http://www.adobe.com/uk/epaper/tips/acr5reflow/)

> In the steps that follow, you'll learn how to create a reflowable Adobe PDF document from a Microsoft® Office 2000 for Windows® document.